# Installing Ubuntu on a USB

Tags: system-installation, usb, live-usb, sata

I made a bootable media drive using UNetBootin and then I plugged it into my PC. After that, I took a 32GB USB flash drive and connected it, as well. Then I booted into the bootable drive and selected "Try Ubuntu without installing" and from the desktop, I selected install Ubuntu, then while installing I selected the 32GB flash drive as the installation destination, is that alright or do I have to select the SATA HDD COMPULSORILY? Is it okay to install on a USB flash drive (I don't mind the slow speed.) I tried doing this on Zorin os and while installing aa error came up saying that the GRUB installation failed. What do I do?

Comment: Do you want to install this on the hard drive, or on the USB? If you select the SATA HDD, Ubuntu will overwrite whatever is on that disk and boot off that disk. If you select the USB, Ubuntu will overwrite and install on the USB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install ubuntu on 32gb usb flash drive, then use UNetBootin and install directly to USB. Installing to USB drive requires UNetBootin. If you want to increase the **storage** of the USB drive you can increase it by using persistence storage slider available in **UNetBootin** installer. The installation process that you are using is for installing to **HDD**. This way you can install to **HDD** only because it install GRUB on HDD. GRUB (Grand Unified Boot Loader) is used for multi boot machine. This way you can install multiple OS(Operating Systems) on the PC. We can install GRUB on USB. But I am not sure whether multiple boot on USB is possible.
Alternatively you can try to use **virtualisation on USB**.I didn't try this myself and can't guarantee any success. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) for details.

Comment: I have had success with Linux virtual machines on flash drive and some failures with Windows vm's, but i recall a few sucesses.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to install 'buntu to a flash drive.
A persistent install uses a file or partition, (casper-rw or home-rw), to store changes. Mkusb works well for doing a persistent install.

A Full install to USB drive is just like an install to internal HDD. 
Most computers now days see usb drives as just another HDD,
Full installs can take a little more disk space but boot faster.
You can use a Persistent USB to do a Full install.

If you have lots of RAM speed should be about the same as an internal install.

How old is your computer? This can affect the method required to boot the drive.